# Redirecionamento de domínio na GoDaddy

Tags: html, redirecionamento, dns, domínio

Eu tenho um domínio na GoDaddy:

```
dominio.com
```

Eu configurei o domínio para redirecionar para:

```
outrodominio.com/~meu_nome
```

Essa página existe e funciona perfeitamente (assim como o redirecionamento).
Entretanto, quando eu chamo na URL:

```
dominio.com/certificado
```

A GoDaddy também redireciona para o domínio principal:

```
outrodomino.com/~meu_nome
```

Mas eu gostaria que ele redicionasse para:

```
outrodominio.com/~meu_nome/certificado
```

Eu acho que preciso configurar a zona de DNS, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso (não sei nem ao certo como pesquisar isso no Google). Já tentei o suporte da GoDaddy, mas não souberam me explicar (o estranho é que esse redirecionamento funcionou perfeitamente por quase 1 ano).

Comment: Cara vc pode por um html vazio na pasta original e dentro desse html vc coloca um script ou a tag meta redirect se não me engano para redirecionar o usuário para onde vc quiser, se precisar de DNS ou htaccess

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português :D Sugiro que faça um [tour] para conhecer como funciona o Stack Overflow. Outra sugestão, dados que não são importantes não precisam nem mesmo serem mencionados e se você postou uma pergunta, logicamente você espera uma resposta, portanto não precisa perguntar sem alguém sabe, e se desejar agradecer é só da um voto positivo na resposta que te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Cara consulta a autoridade DNS saber onde configurar a zona DNS do seu domínio.

Este site te ajuda com isso ipok.com

La vc consegue verificar isso.

Para configurar o site via zona DNS, você deve criar uma entrar do tipo A apontando para o IP do servidor que está hospedando suas informações.

Para abrir uma página específica que não seja na raiz, aí precisa usar script ou alterar o htaccess.

Qualquer coisa retorna a pesquisa e as URLs para testar aqui tbm.